# paste distinct values in R

Tags: r

I am trying to paste distinct values as shown below. But not getting desired output

```
 paste0(c("A","B"),c("A1", "B1"))
[1] "AA1" "BB1"
```

Expected output

```
[1] "AA1" "AB1" "BA1" "BB1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `expand.grid` with `sprintf`:

```
x <- expand.grid( c("A","B"), c("A1", "B1"))
sprintf('%s%s', x[,1], x[,2])
```

```
[1] "AA1" "BA1" "AB1" "BB1"
```

Answer (score 2):

As the `length` of the two vectors are the same, `paste` will do an elementwise pasteing.  To avoid that, `rep`licate one of the vectors and `recycle` the other

```
paste0(rep(c("A","B"), each = 2), c("A1", "B1"))
[1] "AA1" "AB1" "BA1" "BB1"
```

---

Or use `outer` with `paste`

```
c(outer(c("A", "B"), c("A1", "B1"), FUN = paste, sep = ""))
[1] "AA1" "BA1" "AB1" "BB1"
```